# Responsive background-image resizing no-cropping

Tags: html, css, width, background-image, fixed

I'm trying to change a background-image that get cut when the screen resize to let always fit the width of the screen.

I tried adding a new class or changing some parameter but it doesn't work on the background-image.

```
.fixed {
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
 background-size:100%;
}
```

This is the image I need to change, as you can see if you resize the browser it get cut:
http://followmedelivery.com/

This is an example of what I want to get, but they are doing it with img and not with the background-image:
http://followmedelivery.com/wp/

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of code to review if you don't place a fiddle, but maybe this is the problem.

```
transform: translate3d(0px, 19.0805px, 0px);
```

I have check that this style is being applied to your background image, but not by CSS but JS. So you would have to go to the JS file and delete that and check if that make the picture not cut anymore. Give it a try and let me know if that worked out :)

Comment: Thank you Lester, yep there is a lot of complex code and it's really hard for me. I deleted the part of the parallax script that created the transform: translate 3d but is not working.... I'm keeping trying

Comment: Just make sure to delete the 4 statements of transform, because there are not only one